# IIS is closing connection on dynamic content

Tags: iis-6

There is a strange problem I am facing, if any of you might have seen before.

I have freshly install OS (Windows 2003 SP2) and just have configured IIS on it and on the default site,the static content say hello.htm is working fine.But any dynamic content like hello.asp (classic asp) or hello.aspx (asp.net) is not working.

If I telnet and issue HTTP headers manually for static content it works but for dynamic content IIS is basically forcefully closing the connection.

- There's nothing in event logs.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question, but do you have ASP.Net enabled in add/remove programs in and IIS itself? I don't think that would cause it to close the connection, but it is a common "gotcha" along with registering ASP.Net.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET and ASP both are enabled!

Answer (score 0):

Look under **Web Service Extensions** in IIS.

Is ASP.NET marked "enabled"?  Do you see it?  If not, do a `aspnet_regiis -i` from your %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\WHATEVERVERSION\ directory on the command line, and you will.

Then re-check Web Service Extensions and make sure it is enabled.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET and ASP both are enabled!